# Express js execute a function asynchronously every time when the server is restarted

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a requirement to run a function in my Express.js application that reads data from database and caches into Redis. I want to run this function only when the Web server is restarted.

Would you help me with the approach please!

Comment: Please post the code you use to (re)start your server.

Comment: Just run it on startup in your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke the function near the top of your express application Javascript file where you initialize your web app. For example, put it near the `app=express()` line like this

```
var app = express()
loadMyRedisFromMyDatabase()
```